# Win Vista to Win 7 Upgrade problem - Drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, audio, codec

Have just upgraded from Vista Home Premium 32 bit to Win 7 Home Premium 32 bit which appeared to go well but i now have 2 annoying driver problems.

1. Whenever i now boot my computer a message pops up Saying Tages Protection Driver is incompatible and has been disabled.  If i check for solutions it appears to be something connected with an application called Sygate Firewall which in turn seems to be part of Norton Security.   Strangely it is not something i have ever installed though?  Nevertheless as well as not knowing where it came from i do not know how to get rid of it either?!  Any ideas??
2. My IDT High Definition Audio CODEC driver does not seem to work so i have no sound?

I will post back if i find a solution but if anyone has any ideas it would be most helpful.

Comment: You should not post your updates as answers, it confuses people and generally is not good practice. You can update your question with the new input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That driver is installed by several games at part of an anti-piracy solution. Simply update the driver by going [here](http://www.tagesprotection.com/main.htm?page=minimum.htm).

If you do not play the game it is needed for there is no need to try and fix the driver, simply uninstall it. Go to Control Panel -> System and Security -> Device Manager and uninstall the Tages Protection Driver.